# OpenSSL : "unable to verify the first certificate" in every HTTPS site

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I'm not sure what's wrong with my Ubuntu 18.04 server.
I need to setup a web server on it but when I try to install packages from the Ubuntu repository I cannot download any packages because of certificate verification issues.

Then I tried to hit any random https links with curl and wget, it has the same issue too.

when I try to verify any https site's certificate with

```
openssl s_client -connect packagist.org:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I got an error code 21 output from OpenSSL like this.

[image: enter image description here]]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: SOLVED. The problem is on the server's firewall's device that blocks the certificate verification communication process.